# How to get element name to build dynamic elements from it

Tags: jquery

I am building a jQuery function and need to build dynamic elements that will all share a comment name.

```
$('#search').somefunction();
```

Inside of `somefunction` I will loop through all given elements and I then need to create dynamic elements that share a global name

```
 var newName = $(this)
 $('<div id="'+newName+'originalsearch" />')
 $('<div id="'+newName+'newsearch" />')
```

**Problem**

I could do `var newName = $(this).attr('id')`, but being a jquery plugin they could use any form of jquery selector.

So how can I make elements from the original selector without knowing its type?

Comment: the ids have to be unique so just check whether they have id set and when they do not, add them your own?

Comment: You're going to need to explain this a little more. Don't over complicate things, what do you basically need your script to do? If it is just having elements with unique `id`s then just append the counter to the `id` in the loop. You could use a dash to separate the common name section. So `id="originalsearch-1"`, `id="newsearch-1"`, `id="originalsearch-2"`, etc.

Comment: adding numbers could be a good solution. It would mean looking up with `.index` each time though, not really a problem. So yes, i am looking to have a individual name for newly created items. All i wanted to do is get out the selectors name and use this as the unique names on the elements. But as I don't know what the given selector is, i can't use `attr` as a jquery selector is a beautiful thing.

Comment: _But as I don't know what the given selector is_ .. why you want to know the selector ?

Comment: So i can extract the name of the selector give, by name i mean. `$('.jamie')` or `$('#jamie')` will give me `//var item = jamie` meaning I can then create a name element `$('<div class="search'+item+'" />');`

Comment: is anyone's guess what this app is doing at a higher level. Solutions should depend on what that higher level is...explain in more detail. A demo would help